# window functions to solve complex date manipulations

Tags: sql, database, date, window-functions, analysis

I have the following list of transactions:

| transaction_id | transaction_type | spend_year | transaction_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Business | 0 | 2020-11-01 |
| 2 | Supplemental | 0 | 2021-08-23 |
| 3 | Renewal | 1 | 2021-10-15 |
| 4 | Supplemental | 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 5 | Supplemental | 1 | 2022-05-22 |
| 6 | Renewal | 2 | 2022-07-15 |

Note: spend_year is used to group transactions together based on renewal periods.

With the table above, I need to calculate two additional fields:

**(1) spend_year_start_date**

when `spend_year = 0`, this should be the `min(transaction_date)` (this should be the first ever transaction date)

when `spend_year > 0`, this should be the `dateadd('month', -3, (min(transaction_date) over(partition by spend_year)))` i.e. 3 months preceding the renewal transaction date for that spend year

**(2) spend_year_end_date**

this should be the `spend_year_start_date` of the next `spend_year` group

The desired output table should look like this:

| transaction_id | transaction_type | spend_year | transaction_date | spend_year_start_date | spend_year_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Business | 0 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-01 | 2021-07-15 |
| 2 | Supplemental | 0 | 2021-08-23 | 2020-11-01 | 2021-07-15 |
| 3 | Renewal | 1 | 2021-10-15 | 2021-07-15 | 2022-04-15 |
| 4 | Supplemental | 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-07-15 | 2022-04-15 |
| 5 | Supplemental | 1 | 2022-05-22 | 2021-07-15 | 2022-04-15 |
| 6 | Renewal | 2 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-04-15 | null |

I've been experimenting with various window functions, but still can't capture the logic correctly. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `LEAD()` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN spend_year = 0
                   THEN MIN(transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY spend_year)
                   ELSE DATEADD(month, -3, MIN(transaction_date) OVER
                            (PARTITION BY spend_year)) END AS spend_year_start_date
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT spend_year,
           LEAD(MIN(spend_year_start_date)) OVER (ORDER BY spend_year) AS spend_year_lead
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY spend_year
)

SELECT t1.transaction_id, t1.transaction_type, t1.spend_year, t1.transaction_date,
       t1.spend_year_start_date, t2.spend_year_lead AS spend_year_end_date
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2 ON t2.spend_year = t1.spend_year
ORDER BY t1.transaction_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that (next spend_year= current spend_year+1), you may try the following:

```
SELECT T.transaction_id, T.transaction_type, T.spend_year, T.transaction_date,
       CASE 
           WHEN T.spend_year = 0
               THEN MIN(T.transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY T.spend_year)
               ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, -3, MIN(T.transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY T.spend_year)) 
       END AS spend_year_start_date,
       DATEADD(MONTH, -3, D.transaction_date) spend_year_end_date
FROM table_name T
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(transaction_date) transaction_date, spend_year FROM table_name GROUP BY spend_year) D
ON T.spend_year+1 = D.spend_year
ORDER BY T.transaction_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rqjuAq5M).